# Time taken to hit the ground

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag, free-fall

I came across these two statements, please explain to me how the second statement is correct. I think it's incorrect.

1. The time taken to hit the ground is independent of mass, size and shape of a body in **vacuum**.
2. But, **in air**, if two bodies of the same mass and a different size fall, then the body having more volume will take more time.

Comment: Might you explain *why* you think the second statement is incorrect?

Comment: If the second statement is true then how can an egg and watermelon hit the ground at the same moment, if both of them are thrown from the same height? Also they both have different volume, so how can this be true?

Answer (score 2):

This is simply because air exerts a viscous force. A body moving in vacuum have an acceleration independent of it's mass as gravity is the only force acting. However in air, a bigger object experiences more air resistance. Additionally in air a bigger object has more buoyancy.

Comment: So why does an egg and watermelon hits the ground at the same time, if both of them have different volume?

Comment: @ShreyPatel They don't. Its just that the watermelon and the egg have sufficiently large masses that the air resistance and buoyancy pale in comparison, so we observe no noticeable difference.